# How can I iterate over a list of dicts inside a pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe, loops, dictionary

I have a pandas DataFrame looking something like this:

```
    | ID       | col1 | col2 |     col3    |
    | -------- | ---- | ---- | ------------|
    | ID1      | val1 | val1 | [{..},{..}] |
    | ID2      | val2 | val2 | [{..},{..}] |
```

the rows of col3 consist of a list of dicts looking something like this:

```
    [{'key1':'3', 'key2':'8', 'key3':'9'},
     {'key1':'3', 'key2':'8', 'key3':'7'},
     {'key1':'2', 'key2':'1', 'key3':'9'}]
```

The keys within all dicts are the 'same' and I'm trying to add a new column "col4" to my df with a count of e.g. how often the number 8 as value apears in each dict with key2 as key, similar like:

```
    | ID       | col1 | col2 |     col3    | col4 |
    | -------- | ---- | ---- | ------------| ---- |
    | ID1      | val1 | val1 | [{..},{..}] |  2   |
    | ID2      | val2 | val2 | [{..},{..}] |  5   |
```

I don't have any idea how to even start solving this problem, how can I iterate over a list of dicts inside a pandas dataframe?

Comment: Are the values in `col3` actually lists or just strings that look like lists? Try `print(type(df['col3'].iloc[0]))` and `print(type(df['col3'].iloc[0][0]))`

Comment: @richardec they are strings but why do they look like lists?                                        Edit: output is: <class 'str'> <class 'str'>

Comment: That's okay, it's common. See my answer; I updated it to account for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a combination of `explode`, `pd.json_normalize`, `unstack`, and `value_counts`:

```
val = '8'
df['col4'] = df['a'].explode().pipe(lambda x: pd.json_normalize(x).set_index(x.index)).groupby(level=0).apply(lambda g: g.unstack().value_counts()[val])
```

But first you might need to convert the data in your column to actually dicts/lists, because they might just be strings that *look look* dicts/lists:

```
import ast
df['col4'] = df['col4'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Comment: You're my hero, tt works but it doesn't count right how often '8' apears in the dicts/lists. 'col4' has now the value '1' in every row but should have '2' in the first row. How is it possible to adjust that?

Comment: Are you able to provide a sample of your dataframe with `print(df.head(5).to_dict())`?

Comment: unfortunately not :( I just tried to set up a df with a similar structure but I failed

Comment: Can you just run `print(df.head(2).to_dict())` and replace the sensitive data with nonsense, like `asdf`?

Comment: This solutions works nicely for me...I'm guessing your data has a subtle difference somewhere...?

Comment: ok I just found the issue within my df (my sample really had every value just 1 time), your code works now like a charm :) Thank you so much!! the problem was sitting in front of the computer I guess..